# streaming gzipped files from google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-storage

I would like to read compressed files directly from Google Cloud Storage and open them with the Python csv package. 
The code for a local file would be:

```
def reader(self):
    print "reading local compressed file: ", self._filename
    self._localfile = gzip.open(self._filename, 'rb')
    csvReader = csv.reader(self._localfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    return csvReader
```

I have played with several GCS APIs (JSON based, cloud.storage), but none of them seem to give me something that I can stream through gzip. What is more, even if the file was uncompressed, I could not open the file and give it to cv.reader (Iterator type).

My compressed CSV files are about 500MB, while uncompressed they use up to a few GB. I don't think it would be a good idea to: 1 - locally download the files before opening them (unless I can overlap download and computation) or 2 - Open it entirely in memory before computing.

Finally, I current run this code on my local machine, but ultimately, I will move to AppEngine, so it must work there too.

Thanks!!

Comment: What about split your file in multiple parts?

Comment: that's already multiple parts of a 1+TB dataset. :D Breaking it further seems like an unnecessary idea. I'm trying Alex Martelli's suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open), `cloudstorage.open(filename, 'r')` will give you a read-only file-like object (earlier created similarly but with `'w'`:-) which you can use, a chunk at a time, with the standard Python library's [zlib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#module-zlib), specifically a `zlib.decompressobj`, if, of course, the GS object was originally created in the complementary way (with a `zlib.compressobj`).

Alternatively, for convenience, you can use the standard Python library's [gzip module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#module-gzip), e.g for the reading phase something like:

```
compressed_flo = cloudstorage.open('objname', 'r')
uncompressed_flo = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_flo,mode='rb')
csvReader = csv.reader(uncompressed_flo)
```

and vice versa for the earlier writing phase, of course.

Note that when you run locally (with the dev_appserver), the GCS client library uses **local disk files** to simulate GCS -- in my experience that's good for development purposes, and I can use `gsutil` or other tools when I need to interact with "real" GCS storage from my local workstation... GCS is for when I need such interaction from my GAE app (and for developing said GAE app locally in the first place:-).

Comment: "if, of course, the GS object was originally created in the complementary way (with a zlib.compressobj)" -- why this limitation? This should work with any valid gzipped file content, right? Not that I tested, but the zlib module's heading is " zlib — Compression compatible **with gzip**" ;-).

Comment: `gzip` adds metadata that `zlib` doesn't know nor care about -- after which `gzip` compresses the data body with `zlib`, but still does a lot of metadata work, such as crc maintenance.  See http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Lib/gzip.py for the sources of `gzip.py` -- 500+ lines of code **on top of** `zlib`!-)  Nothing to do with GCS of course -- do your own dumping to/restoring from a local disk file and you'll have identical issues. Best, simplest, smartest: either let `gzip` work both ways, or, if the metadata's dead baggage for you, `zlib` both ways (save a few bytes).

Comment: I agree that, for simplicity, one should use the same tool both ways. However, I was now curious about why the zlib module claims "Compression compatible with gzip", and had a peek into the docs at http://www.zlib.net. Turns out that *"gzip adds metadata that zlib doesn't know nor care about"* is not really correct. `zlib` can automatically detect the `gzip` wrapper (header + footer) and can ignore it, depending on the `windowBits` setting. In Python this feature is also exposed, via the `wbits` argument to `zlib.decompressobj()`. That's interesting. I have added example code to my answer.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke it's interesting in the abstract, but falls under my "if the metadata's dead baggage to you" condition: yes you can ignore it more easily than I thought, but, if you're ignoring it anyway, why bother storing it in the first place and paying for its storage?-)

Comment: Right, and I think we are on the same page here ;). My take home message from this is just that `zlib` can decompress a lot more than I initially thought, and this functionality is not clearly documented in the Python (2) docs.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, you're right, and a patch to said docs would I suspect be welcome!

Answer (score 4):

So, you have gzipped files stored on GCS. You can process the data stored on GCS *in a stream-like fashion*. That is, you can download, unzip, and process simultaneously. This avoids

- to have the unzipped file on disk
- to have to wait until the download is complete before being able to process the data.

gzip files have a small header and footer, and the body is a compressed stream, consisting of a series of blocks, and each block is decompressable on its own. Python's [zlib package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) helps you with that!

**Edit:** This is example code for how to decompress and analzye a zlib or gzip stream chunk-wise, purely based on `zlib`:

```
import zlib
from collections import Counter


def stream(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            yield chunk


def decompress(stream):
    # Generate decompression object. Auto-detect and ignore
    # gzip wrapper, if present.
    z = zlib.decompressobj(32+15)
    for chunk in stream:
        r = z.decompress(chunk)
        if r:
            yield r


c = Counter()
s = stream("data.gz")
for chunk in decompress(s):
    for byte in chunk:
        c[byte] += 1


print c
```

I tested this code with an example file `data.gz`, created with GNU `gzip`.

Quotes from http://www.zlib.net/manual.html:

> windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip decoding. Add
>   32 to windowBits to enable zlib and gzip decoding with automatic
>   header detection, or add 16 to decode only the gzip format (the zlib
>   format will return a Z_DATA_ERROR). If a gzip stream is being decoded,
>   strm->adler is a crc32 instead of an adler32.

and

> Any information contained in the gzip header is not retained [...]